# Undefined reference to static member

Tags: c++, gcc

I have a static member in my class. It's declared and defined:

In my header:

```
class Bla {
...
static Bla* instance;
...
};
```

In my implementation file:

```
Bla::Bla* instance = 0;
```

But ld doesn't seems to like it:

```
release/bla.o:bla.cpp:(.text+0x19f7): undefined reference to `Bla::instance'
```

I'm using GCC 4.4.0 from the Qt SDK.

I can't figure it out what I'm doing wrong. Can someone shed a light on this issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You missed a `Bla`, and instead created a global. Make it:

```
Bla* Bla::instance = 0;
```